# what do users respond best to when providing social bookmarking possibilities

Tags: social-media, facebook, google+

I'm looking for what will get me most social media attention. I have a site that provides insurance information, so it would be used by most people, in the footer I'm going to place some social bookmarking possibilities, but I can't make out what to present to the user.

Is it better to just have: Facebook, google and twitter so the user has few and well known options, or would it attract most social media attention if I use AddThis and provide a massive list of social media bookmarking possibilities - what are your thoughts/experiences?

Comment: I'd first ask the question "How many people are into posting insurance information to facebook and twitter"? I'm perhaps cynical, but I don't think every web site needs social media links.

Comment: I must've mislead you guys, I'll try to rephrase - it's not that they're posting insurance information to those social sites, just that they're recommending the site to others through facebook and twitter

Comment: well, that seems even worse. How many people spam their friends insurance info on Facebook and Twitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to agree with DA01 to an extent if you're just looking at social bookmarking alone.

But I think the best way to approach this would be to look at this from another perspective.

I suggest you "adopt" some compelling content alongside your social bookmarks and have your information (***hitch a ride***). Honestly, if you don't do this - no one is going to share your content with their friends.

Don't go for the all in the barrel of social bookmarking services. There have been [studies](http://www.apa.org/monitor/jun04/toomany.aspx) on User Behavior that when given too many choices, the user becomes overwhelmed and chooses none.

I would check out the [Ucubd](http://www.ucubd.com) template "[Tube Tweets](http://ucubd.com/tubetweets.html)" where you can add a viral video next to your insurance companies Twitter feed, enhancing engagement and sharability.

---

http://www.ucubd.com

http://ucubd.com/tubetweets.html

http://www.apa.org/monitor/jun04/toomany.aspx

Comment: thank you very much. good resources - I don't really dig the format or color scheme of the ucubd widget however, do you know of any similar sergices I can check out?

Comment: if you have a social media presence, check out [wibya](http://www.wibya.com) which consolidates those services into a little bar on your website.